# How to get every element from a list of list (matrix) using for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
M = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]
    
for i in range(len(M)): 
    print(M[i][i])
```

How to get the element of an element in a list within a loop in python

I can't remember, it's seems to work with M[i][0] or M[i][1]  but I want to do it within a loop

Comment: Do you want to have a nested `for` loop?

Comment: for loop inside a for loop

Comment: I don't know It doesn't seems to work with nested loop either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can use indexes to traverse the elements using `[:]` accessing operator for lists:

```
M = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]

for i in range(len(M)):
  for j in range(len(M[i])):
    print(M[i][j])
```

Comment: if it is an np.array you can also use M[i, j]

Comment: @irazza It would be great if Numpy were used here, but the OP didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

To see all the numbers on separate lines:

```
for entry in M:
    for i in entry:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Or print the sublist in one line:   -for completeness: `for lst in M:
 print(*lst)`

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using list comprehension is required output is list

```
[j for i in M for j in i ]
```